# Reject Changes Does Not Remove Entity From Parent

Tags: breeze

When I create a new entity and set its navigation property and then reject the changes the parent holds onto a blank entity.  Do I need to explicitly remove the new entity from the parent before rejecting changes?  I did not explicitly add it to the parent I just set the new entity's parent id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rejecting changes on a new entity simply discards the entity - making its entityState 'detached'.  Any children that were attached to the parent effectively get stranded in this case, i.e. they have no parent.

In other words, Breeze does NOT call **rejectChanges** on any children as a result of a rejectChanges on a parent.  This is deliberate.

So your best bet is to call **rejectChanges** on the children as well. If they were new entities themselves they will also become detached, otherwise their parents will revert to whichever entity was their previous parent.

Note that you can use the EntityManager.getEntities method to return all of the entities of specified entityTypes and entityStates.  This can be useful in determining which entities you want to 'roll back'.

See the [Entity Manager getEntities method](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_getEntities)

Comment: Thanks, sorry it took so long to reply. Your answer helped greatly.

Comment: @Jay Traband, are there any guidelines for automatically reset-ing the Breeze client-side entity manager when a User navigates/leaves screens? I'm finding I need to place repetitive code across my screen components, so that if a User clicks to edit a record, changes a field, then click Cancel... I need to make sure the EntityManager forgets about any pending model changes (since field inputs are bound directly to entity properties). Or else when .saveChanges is called later, Breeze is trying to also include the previous changes.

Comment: You can use EntityManager.rejectChanges to clear any changes to everything or use EntityAspect.rejectChanges to rejectChanges for a single entity.  i.e. myEntity.entityAspect.rejectChanges()